# SET path with space doesnt work

Tags: batch-file

pleas help.

```
SET "prog=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe"

SET "file=%prog%\Color\Profiles\%Value%"


FOR /f %%i IN ("%file%") DO (

ECHO filename=%%~ni
ECHO path=%%~fi
pause
)
```

Result:

filename=Program 
path=C:/Program

I need path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\Color\Profiles\%Value%
and filename %Value% no Program...
Thx.

Comment: Fascinating.  When I try `"test=\"j k h\""` it complains that `\"j h k\"` is not recognized, but with your code it says `j` is not recognized.  How very strange.  `set test="j h k"` complains that `"j h k"` is not found, so quotes only half work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FOR /F` command as you wrote it is designed to process *A STRING* enclosed in quotes. This way, the following command:

```
FOR /f %%i IN ("%file%") DO (
```

place in `%%i` variable the first token of *such string* ("C:\Program") and `%%~ni` tries to extract a file name from such string!

If you want to extract the name *of the file*, you should use a plain FOR command with NO /F option:

```
FOR %%i IN ("%file%") DO (
   ECHO filename=%%~ni
   ECHO path=%%~fi
   pause
)
```

What I tried to mean is that in this case you want to process the `%file%` variable contents as a *file name*, NOT as a *string*, so you should use a plain `FOR` command designed to process files (instead `FOR /F` designed to process strings).

Comment: I mostly agree, except I disagree with the phrase "you must use a plain FOR command". FOR /F certainly works if the proper options are used ("delims="). The simple FOR is indeed simpler, but it is not wrong to use FOR /F.

Comment: @dbenham: I changed "must" by "should"  `;-)`  I just wanted to state that there is no reason to use FOR /F in this case...

Answer (score 1):

If you change your FOR line to this, you'll get results closer to what you want:

```
FOR /f "DELIMS=" %%i IN ("%file%") DO (
```

OR

```
FOR /f "TOKENS=*" %%i IN ("%file%") DO (
```

The specified TOKENS and DELIMS parsing options allow the FOR to accept the whole string from %file% into %i and ignore spaces.  Source:  http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/for.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: You can drop the word "may" - that will definitely solve the problem. However, you don't need both. Either "TOKENS=*" or "DELIMS=" will solve the problem. The OP's code fails because the default FOR /F delimiters are space and tab.

Comment: @dbenham Ah, thanks for the pointer about not needing both options.  I wasn't 100% sure some unforeseen (by less-than-expert me) edge cases wouldn't mess things up.

Comment: They are not quite equivalent. "DELIMS=" will preserve the entire line. "TOKENS=*" will strip leading spaces and tabs. But in many cases, including this one, there are no leading spaces or tabs. So people get in the habit of using "TOKENS=*". I prefer to use "DELIMS=" unless I explicitly want to trim leading spaces/tabs.